# Transitions from one element to another

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am implementing an automated help function in my code. It is simply a few bubbles that pop up with some text in them. I use d3 to select one bubble, display it for a short time, and then select another bubble and display that one. It works, but I don't like the shape the code is taking. Am I approaching this correctly?

```
d3.select("#targetYear-bubble")
    .transition().duration(2000)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .transition().duration(2000)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .each("end", function()
        {
            d3.select("#navTree-bubble").transition().duration(2000)
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .transition().duration(2000)
                .style("opacity", 0);
        })
        ;
```

This code displays 2 pop-up bubbles. It's manageable for now, but if I had a complex screen with 7 or 8 (or more) bubbles, this code would be much too complex.

Can someone make a suggestion for a better implementation of this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.  Your first question has been reviewed and accepted.  I expect that you'll get a number of useful reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you chain with each then its has to be a recursive structure like that.

I like the mediator pattern for this...

```js
var mediator = d3.dispatch('phase1', 'phase2'),

 bubbles = d3.selectAll(".bubbles")
   .style("opacity", 0.5);

   
 mediator.on('phase1', function(then) {
      
  d3.select(".bubble1")
  .transition().duration(2000)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .transition().duration(2000)
   .style("opacity", 0)
  .each('end.phase1', function () { mediator[then]() })
        
 });

 mediator.on('phase2', function() {
      
  d3.select(".bubble2")
  .transition().duration(2000)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .transition().duration(2000)
   .style("opacity", 0);
      
 });

 mediator.phase1('phase2');
```

```html
<div class="bubbles bubble1">bubble1</div>
    <div class="bubbles bubble2">bubble2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It's much easier to automate

Comment: Nice. I Used your suggestion and the code is instantly easier to maintain and grow. I did, however, leave out the line that selects all ".bubbles" in the beginning. No need for it that I can see.

Comment: Yes, its much easier to understand but still declarative and data-driven and the coupling is simpler.  The first selection was just there so that I could style the divs so I could see them for test purposes.  I don't like seeing a blank page when it loads... d3 is already scary enough without that!